# Setting class variable during instantiation when using a factory in python

Tags: python, factory-pattern

I have a class factory, very similar to the one [here](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Factory.html#polymorphic-factories). I want to set a variable that the created class will have access to, when calling createShape. How do you do this pythonicly?

For example:

```
foo = 'bar'
circle = ShapeFactory.createShape('circle', foo)
print circle.foo >>> bar
```

however, since createShape is static, I can't add

```
self.foo = foo
```

to the createShape method.

Obviously all shapes would implement this parameter.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you wouldn't simply use `circle.foo`, or why `self.foo` is pythonic.

Comment: Pythoinc was, I suppose the wrong word here. Just wanted to know how to pass parameters to the create method of a factory-made object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with `self`, but you can still do it with the object created in `createShape`.  That code does this in `createShape`:

```
return ShapeFactory.factories[id].create()
```

So just do this:

```
myShape = ShapeFactory.factories[id].create()
myShape.foo = foo
return myShape
```

However, looking at the example on the page you linked to, I can't say I'd recommend that approach at all.  The design described in that example is very awkward.

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do! Not sure how I missed this. First time implementing a factory this way in Python, I'll look at some more examples. Thanks.